# How do I do this particular alignment between a group of inputs and their labels, and a single button?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

[image]

This is the specific kind of alignment that I am trying to achieve, but it's so tricky because of the labels. Without the labels, I can just group the inputs and the button, and use align items center, and it's done, but the labels expand the height, and messes the position of the button.

I tried using two rows, one for the labels, and one for the inputs + button below them, and it worked, but it only works on large devices, on smaller devices it's not working.

Another solution that I have thought about is using position absolute on the labels, but I don't think that would be a good idea.

Yet another solution is to use pseudo-elements for the labels.

And of course the last solution that I can think of is to use align-self for the button to adjust it at the bottom, and then use margins or padding to align it the way it needs to be, but I don't think this approach is good.

Can anyone think of any better way of doing it? What would be the best approach in your opinion?

Below I am copying the code that I tried with two words. You have to run it with bootstrap.

```html
<div class="d-flex align-items-end pb-4">
                <div class="w-100">
                    <!-- Label wrapper -->
                   <div class="row gx-3">
                    <div class="col-9  row gx-3 align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <label class="form-label" for="input1">Label</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <label class="form-label" for="input2">Label</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <label class="form-label" for="input3">Label</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                   <!-- Input wrapper -->
                   <div class="row gx-3">
                    <div class="col-9 row gx-3 align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="input1" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <select class="form-select" id="input2">
                                <option selected value="default">Select</option>
                                <option value="1">One</option>
                                <option value="2">Two</option>
                                <option value="3">Three</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <select class="form-select" id="input3">
                                <option selected value="default">Select</option>
                                <option value="1">One</option>
                                <option value="2">Two</option>
                                <option value="3">Three</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Please feel free to recreate that particular image the way you think it would work.
I am not providing any code for the other ways I thought of doing it because it's too basic. I am sure just describing it is enough. It's just a flex container with inputs inside. That's it, but when an input is wrapped with a label, then the 'search' button at the end is not aligned with the input only, but both, the input + label wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple use flexbox for vertical-aligning:

Edited:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="d-flex gap-3 flex-row align-items-center position-relative" style="padding-top: 1.25em">
    <div class="col-3">
        <label for="input1" class="position-absolute top-0">Label</label>
        <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="input1" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <label for="input2" class="position-absolute top-0">Label</label>
        <select class="form-select d-block" id="input2">
            <option selected value="default">Select</option>
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <label for="input3" class="position-absolute top-0">Label</label>
        <select class="form-select d-block" id="input3">
            <option selected value="default">Select</option>
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The button in your snippet is not aligned in the middle of the other inputs, but rather its bottom is aligned with the other input's bottom. Look at the image again.

Comment: I see now, edited post.

Comment: Is using position for the labels the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

I just used **tailwind** to implement the solution of what you asked.

```
<div class="flex gap-4 items-end">
  <div class="flex flex-col">
    <label>label a</label>
    <input type="text" class="w-24" />
  </div>
   <div class="flex flex-col">
    <label>label a</label>
    <input type="text" class="w-24" />
  </div>
   <div class="flex flex-col">
    <label>label a</label>
    <input type="text" class="w-24" />
  </div>
   <div class="flex flex-col">
    <input type="button" class="w-24 bg-gray-300 p-2" value="button" />
  </div>
</div>
```

You can check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4mqsx0j/) as well

Answer (score 0):

Invisible fourth element on the labels row in combination with `flex:1 0 0` to space the elements evenly and match top row with bottom row.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.inputs,
.labels {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.labels:after {
  content: '';
}

.inputs>div,
.labels:after,
.labels>div {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}


/* Gotta deal with input weirdness */

input {
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  animation: x 2s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes x {
  from {
    height: 20px;
  }
  to {
    height: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- Label wrapper -->
  <div class="labels">
    <div>
      <label>Label</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Label</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Label</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Input wrapper -->
  <div class="inputs">
    <div>
      <input />
    </div>
    <div>
      <select>
        <option>Select</option>
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
        <option>Three</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <select>
        <option>Select</option>
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
        <option>Three</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```